# Best way to store html template (Laravel 5)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building an app where the user is able to load some html template and modify it. So i need to store the base html template and the modified one.

I was naturally going to store the html in the database as TEXT (mysql). But i read here and there that this make the database very slow and we should store it as a file.

Any thought on that case while using Laravel 5 ? How should i store HTML template in Laravel ?

Comment: If you don't want to store it in the database you could use your storage directory: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#storing-files

Comment: You can use something else than mysql if you have only performance issues. Check nosql databases / cache systems (mongodb, eleastic search, redis etc...).

Comment: how large are the templates anyway? how many bytes?

Comment: @AlekseiMaide it's like 20 lines of html

Comment: @TheShun I don't think you need to worry about the DB becoming slow unless it doesnt fit into a single DB page (overflows) and 20 lines of html seems less than 8060 bytes (in mysql)

Comment: Wait, you read here and there that it's SLOW and you just took that for granted? No, it isn't slow, and if you store it on disk - nothing will be faster, it just won't be easily scalable. All these "suggestions" with redis, nosql etc are so stupid, is there really that many people who have literally NO CLUE what happens? Store it in the db, use it, if it's slow - fix it later. Worst case scenario is that it's going to perform as reading the template from disk.

Comment: @N.B. Thanks for your reply, i was also thinking about scalability issue ...

Comment: @N.B. hello i am also facing same issue can i store HTMl in to db or in files please also suggest me

Answer (score -1):

You could use [Redis](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/redis). Should be faster than MySQL, although I don't think it will be suitable for very large amounts of data. If you have a laracasts Account, their [series "Learn Redis through examples"](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-laravel-and-redis-through-examples) will give you a kickstart.